# numberposts? showposts? posts_per_page?

Tags: wp-query, customization, codex

So [the documentation on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) is pretty clear that showposts is deprecated. But that same documentation mentions nothing of numberposts. Instead, posts_per_page is listed.

But if we turn to the [Codex docs for get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) we see no mention of posts_per_page, instead citing numberposts.

In [post.php we see what's happening](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L1365): numberposts is set up as a default (5), but then copied to posts_per_page (unless posts_per_page is set in the args).

So my question is really quite pedantic, but I'm looking to update Codex so I wanted to ask you guys - is there a reason why we wouldn't want to just encourage posts_per_page across the board, eventually deprecating numberposts? Or am I missing some critical insight here?

Comment: Since numberposts is deprecated, it's best a best practice to use posts_per_page from here out.

Comment: @Brian, can you point me to where you see that numberposts is officially deprecated? I couldn't find it anywhere in the source.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to showposts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters I apologize.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, deprecating `numberposts` would not make sense, as `numberposts` is used to query *x* amount of posts, whilst `posts_per_page` is used to denote how many posts per page are being shown during pagination. If you were to deprecate `numberposts` in favor of simply `posts_per_page`, then pagination would not exist.

ie:

`"numberposts" => 50, "posts_per_page" => 10`

a total of 50 posts to query, 10 posts per page, giving 5 pages of 10 posts each.

removal of `numberposts`:

`"posts_per_page" => 50`

a total of 50 posts to query, 50 posts per page (since it copies the value of `numberposts` to `posts_per_page`), giving 1 page of 50 posts and no pagination.

Let me know if I'm just reiterating what you're already aware of, and I'm just slightly confused by the question.

Comment: I agree that they __sound__ like they should do different things, but if you study the code, they actually don't! I actually prefer "numberposts" in some cases, like where the notion of "pages" doesn't really come into play - like some output in a sidebar widget, for instance.

Comment: I think `numberposts` is needed when you need to query all posts by passing `-1` which you can't do with `posts_per_page`

Comment: @iSaumya not true - the docs for WP_Query pagination params [explicitly say](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) you can pass `posts_per_page = -1`

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query` class has `posts_per_page` param, meanwhile `get_posts` function has the `numberposts` param. In the `get_posts` function docs page it states:

> 'numberposts'(int) Total number of posts to retrieve. Is an alias of $posts_per_page in WP_Query. Accepts -1 for all. Default 5.

[In the get_posts() code reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) in the source code you can see, it uses `numberposts` value, when `posts_per_page` is empty, so that's how it's an 'alias' (or fallback) for it.

> if ( ! empty( $parsed_args['numberposts'] ) && empty( $parsed_args['posts_per_page'] ) ) {
> $parsed_args['posts_per_page'] = $parsed_args['numberposts'];
> ...

At least, that's how i read it.