# Post images not displaying as attachments

Tags: attachments

I am trying to display the images attached to a post in `single.php` I've used :

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_parent' => $post->ID
);


$attachments = get_posts($args);

if ($attachments) : ?>
    <ul class="portfolio-image-list">

    <?php foreach($attachments as $attachment): ?>
        <li class="box">
        <figure>
        <?php the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, true); ?>
            <figcaption><?php echo $attachment->post_title; ?></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php else : ?>

            <p>No images found for this post.</p>

<?php endif; ?>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

However, the image seems to be in the post content (as confirmed by `var_dump($post)` and there are no attachments `var_dump($attachments)` gives me an empty array.

I seem to be misunderstanding something here...

`var_dump($post);` gives me :

```
 object(WP_Post)#136 (25) { 
 ["ID"]=> int(91) 
 ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-09-04 13:14:17" 
 ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-09-04 13:14:17" 
 ["post_content"]=> string(285) "Snowy Egret"
 ["post_title"]=> string(11) "Snowy Egret"
 ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
 ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
 ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open"
 ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open"
 ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
 ["post_name"]=> string(11) "snowy-egret"
 ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
 ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
 ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2013-09-06 08:36:01"
 ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-09-06 08:36:01      
 ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) ""
 ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
 ["guid"]=> string(44) "/trouble_focusing/?p=91" 
 ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
 ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post"
 ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
 ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
 ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
 ["format_content"]=> NULL
}
```

Comment: Try using posts_per_page in place of numberposts. For more information visit this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28929/numberposts-showposts-posts-per-page

Comment: tried it. No luck :( Interesting though...

Comment: Try removing <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> <?php endwhile; ?> <?php endif; ?> this code.

Comment: tried that too. Funny, its exactly the same.

Comment: Can you show me output of var_dump($post) ?

Comment: How do you say there are attachments for post from above var_dump($post); ?

Comment: It seems all my attachments are attached to another post although they appear in the editing window. I guess the problem is on the admin end.

Comment: You should check it by selecting "Show attachments attched to this post" from drop down menu in media uploader.

Comment: The code works to retrieve attachments for a particular post. I think that you are expecting something to work in a way that it doesn't, but I can't tell exactly what.

Comment: I didn't realise how images could not be unattached from a post without deleting them and thought they were attached only by virtue of being in the post content. Thanks @Vinrod Dalvi that does help. I have it sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Try query post instead of $attachments = get_posts($args);
or do it like

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

also check this url http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I think you might be missing some code there.

Comment: also try "posts_per_page "

Comment: No, that gets me a list of attachments. I want only those connected with the single post.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39241/get-all-image-from-single-page-using-this-query

Comment: is that code working?

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the media uploader. I had the posts attached to another post rather than unattached as media. Thanks for your help.